# Different screen sizes for android

Tags: android, size, screen

I am designing an android game, and have so far test it only on a 480 x 800 pixel emulator, obviously this isn't suitable for all phones. I completely understand with layouts and xml and drawables the need to create them in different sizes, but what about when it comes to canvas methods such as drawing bitmaps, because they would be drawn in different positions on different size screens etc

Thanks in advance

Ben

Answer (score 1):

Personally I dont use different size images for different phones, my images are scales up/down depending on the phone but I make sure the resolution looks good on all phones.

It depends how you have coded really, best way to find out is to scale some of your objects and try it on a different emulator. If its all messed up you will need to make changes.

Have you made the game by pure points such as x = 200, y = 200 of have you done something like x = screenLength/3, y = screenHeight/10?

Comment: Its currently pure points, but i imagine it all has to be done in relation to screen length and height?

Comment: well that is one way of doing it, you may want to consider just scaling the canvas you are drawing to though. That way you can use the pure points way at your desired resolution and then when it is drawn everything gets scale up or down depending on the screen size

Comment: First you need to set a framebuffer (just make it 480x800 in your case) and then use new Canvas(frameBuffer). However the "frameBuffer" needs to be a Bitmap so use frameBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameBufferWidth,
                frameBufferHeight, Config.RGB_565);

Comment: It a bit in depth for just a comment but if you can do it it means it can work on every phone

Comment: so how would framebuffer change from phone to phone?

Comment: It wouldnt you would set the framebuffer to be the preferred screen size and then the canvas will be scaled to the screen width/height. It is the screen width/height that would change but your framebuffer would remain the same

Comment: So would this scale all my position co-ordinates as well to fit the screen sizes?

Comment: It should be in its own class which is used to handle drawing the graphics. There is a really good book that pretty much gives you the code to do this http://www.apress.com/9781430230427

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't just the number of pixels, but also how many pixels are in an inch.  That's why Android uses "[density independence pixels](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence)".  If you follow Android's dpi conventions and allow it to fit bitmaps for you, you'll find that scaling, positioning, etc. becomes automatic.

Comment: yeah but currently i am working with a screen on 600 pixels, and when an object reaches 560 a method is called starting a new round etc. However on a smaller screen, 560 doesn't exist. I get that android will scale bitmaps but how does it scale positioning if its hard coded?